# Expected value of OR gate

Tags: probability, risk-assessment

Suppose a system such as A+B where + means OR. Suppose A and B are identical. Each event obeys exponential distribution with mean $\lambda$.

What is the mean $\lambda_{\text{System}}$ for the whole system?

Comment: I think the E(T) is larger for larger OR gate. Example $\lambda_A=10$ and $\lambda_B=2$: now $E(A+B)=10+2$? This must be different if $Cov(A,B)\not = 0$.

Comment: $\lambda_A\lambda_B/(\lambda_A+\lambda_B)$. (As regards the way this question is asked, definitely "We can do better. We have to do better.")

Comment: @Did that is unintuitive -- $10*2/(12)<2$?! How did you deduce it?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ the probability of the input being a logic 1?

Comment: @ZettaSuro you mean something related to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level? So just ones and zero? I think the events can be not just 0/1 but other numbers as well such as decimals. Did I answer your Q?

Comment: I see, so this is addition, rather than an OR operation? I've never seen an OR operation used on real numbers before.

Comment: hhh: See the parenthesis in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the interpretation of the question that supports the answer in Did's comment.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are two logical variables (inputs to an OR gate) that have
value $0$ at time $t=0$  and change to value $1$ at times $t_1=X$ and
$t_2=Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are modeled as independent exponential random variables with
*parameters* $\theta_X$ and $\theta_Y$ respectively, and thus *means* 
$\frac{1}{\theta_X}=\lambda_X$ and $\frac{1}{\theta_Y}=\lambda_Y$
respectively.  If $C = A\vee B$ is the
output of the OR gate, then $C$ also has initial value $0$ at $t=0$ and changes
to $1$ at time $Z = \min\{X, Y\}=\min\{t_1,t_2\}$.  It is straightforward to verify that $Z$ is also an exponential random variable whose parameter is
$\theta_X+\theta_Y$. The *expected value* of $Z$ is
$$E[Z] = \frac{1}{\theta_X+\theta_Y} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\lambda_X}+\frac{1}{\lambda_Y}}
= \frac{\lambda_X\lambda_Y}{\lambda_X+\lambda_Y}.$$

Comment: Well done. Now to the OP to say if this is their mathematical question...

Comment: I cannot fully understand this: what about if you had an AND gate with OR gate like $T=AB*(C+D)$. Is this correct $E(T)=E(A)*E(B)*(1/(E(C)+E(D))$?

Comment: @hhh That is a different question. Why don't you try and see if you understand the answer to the simpler question that you have asked before asking about more complicated things?

Comment: Not really, I cannot understand $E[Z]=\frac{1}{\theta_x+\theta_y}$ -- why not $E[Z]=\frac{1}{\theta_x}+\frac{1}{\theta_y}$? Or something else, I am trying to reflect and see how it is with slightly different system.

Comment: @hhh $E[Z] = \frac{1}{\theta_X+\theta_Y}$ because $Z$ is an exponential random variable with _parameter_ $\theta_X+\theta_Y$ and hence has density $(\theta_X+\theta_Y)\exp(-(\theta_X+\theta_Y)z)\mathbf 1_{0 \leq z < \infty}$. Work out the details of the computation of $E[Z]$ yourself.